# A problem on polynomial operators

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $p(z)=\sum_{k=1}^na_kz^k$ be a polynomial of degree $n.$ Then we have these two results;

1. If $p(z)\neq 0 $ in $\{|z|<1\}$ then
   $$
   np(z)+(\alpha-z)p'(z)\neq 0\label{1}\tag{1}
   $$  for all $z,\alpha$ in $\{|z|<1\}.$
2. If $p(z)\neq 0 $ in $\{|z|<1\}$ then
   $$n\left(1-(\frac{|a_0|-|a_n|}{n(|a_0|+|a_n|)})\right)p(z)+(\alpha-z)p'(z)\neq 0 \label{2}\tag{2}
   $$ for all $z,\alpha$ in $\{|z|<1\}$.

Let us generalise these two properties. Suppose $\gamma$ is any complex number with
$$
P(z)=\sum_{k=1}^na_kz^k\neq \gamma
$$
for all $z$ in $\{|z|<1\}$. Then we can easily check applying \eqref{1} to $P(z)-\gamma$ that
$$
nP(z)+(\alpha-z)P'(z)\neq n\gamma
\label{3}\tag{3}$$ for all $z,\alpha$ in $\{|z|<1\}$.

I have been trying this property on \eqref{2}. Here we have problem of coefficients!

1. **Now is it true that**
   $$
   n\left(1-(\frac{|a_0|-|a_n|}{n(|a_0|+|a_n|)})\right)P(z)+(\alpha-z)P'(z)\neq n\left(1-(\frac{|a_0|-|a_n|}{n(|a_0|+|a_n|)})\right)\gamma
   $$ **for all $z,\alpha$ in $\{|z|<1\}$ ?**
   [It is true if $a_0$ is replaced by $a_0-\gamma$].
2. **If not for the general case, is it true if we have additional hypothesis that $P(z)\neq 0$ in $|z|<1$ ?**
3. **\eqref{3} implies |$P(z)+(\alpha-z)\frac{P'(z)}{n}|\leq \max_{|z|=1}|P(z)|$ on $|z|=1.$ Is it true that |$P(z)+(\alpha-z)\frac{P'(z)}{n\left(1-(\frac{|a_0|-|a_n|}{n(|a_0|+|a_n|)})\right)}|\leq \max_{|z|=1}|P(z)|$ on $|z|=1?$ (with/without the hypothesis $P(z)\neq 0$ in $|z|<1$)**